# Pipelines in C - Do I have to use fork?

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, inter-process-communicat

Let's just assume I'm working with C only, in a Linux environment.

Normally, if you want to use a pipe() function, you would create a pipe and then fork it, thereby allowing the parent to communicate with the child, and vice-versa.

But what if It's not a parent and child? If I have an old process that's running, is it possible to communicate with it using the pipe() function? This process is not a parent of(or related in any way to) my current process, but I have it's pid. Am I restricted to file or socket for interprocess communication?

Is there any way I can possibly specify a pid and receive information from it without using sockets?

Comment: Your question is too broad, you don't explain what are the two processes doing! Please *edit your question* to improve it!

Answer (score 1):

Or use [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)-s, a.k.a. *named pipes*, or use [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets; read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) to get some more possibilities. See also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

You could also use some shared memory and semaphores, see [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) & [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html), or (as commented by [RADAR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3950946/radar)) message queues, see [mq_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html). But using [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)-s for IPC is generally a bad idea.

Be aware that [inter-processor communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) requires generally cooperation and modifications of both processes; in other words you should probably change the code of both you old A & your initiating B processes! And you probably don't want process A to leak information without consent.

BTW, you might also share memory using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) e.g. on a common file. But you need some synchronization.

Read also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html); thru `/proc/1234/` you can query some informations about process 1234.

BTW, while indeed [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s are very often set up (using [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)) before calling [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) between parent and child processes this is not mandatory. In particular, there are cases where you want a process to pipe to itself (e.g. for [Unix signal delivery in Qt](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/unix-signals.html)).

Answer (score 1):

For Your question

> But what if It's not a parent and child? If I have an old process
>   that's running, is it possible to communicate with it using the pipe()
>   function?

You will not be able to communicate with any other process, which aren't created by the parent process.  Well technically, you shouldn't be allowed to.

You need to go through OS or use other IPC mechanisms to attain this functionality.

The Databases are Widely used just because of this primary reason. Multiple processes will be able to read and write data to a single DB. With protection from Multiple updates.